# What exactly is the input to the coder part of a software video codec?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, codec

I am doing a project based on video codecs and have to implement a specific type of codec(one of the H.26x types). So far in my research, I've found out that mp4 files are simply container files that can contain video data in any coded form. I wanted to know if there is a raw file type for video files like how there are for images and audio. However, I came to find out that there is no standard raw file for a video format and since mp4 is a container, it may as well contain a completely uncompressed video with frames, audio etc.

So basically, if there's no specific standard raw format for a video, what kind of file would the software codec take as input while encoding? And if it does take an mp4, how do we find out if it's really an uncompressed mp4 file or an already encoded one, i.e. which atom holds the value of encoding name?

Edit:

Comment: The encoder takes raw frames which can be in any format supported by that particular codec. If the source is already encoded you need to decode the frames and feed them to the other encoder (transcoding). MP4 doesn't support raw video.

Comment: But these raw frames must be in a file right? there's no specific filetype or container for that? and also which atom contains the encoding name?

Comment: No they can be in a block of memory (which is always the case in transcoding). The pixel format (`yuv420`, `rgb24`,  etc.) defines how to interpret the bit sequence.

Comment: OK so for transcoding, i understand we have to decode a video and then encode it in another format which would mean it would be in memory when encoding, but what about simply encoding and not transcoding? Also are there any good resources on how to write a codec?